# How to invoke activity in another class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I want to create a class for my activity(for instructions) . In new class, I copy the code below in the program, but android studio cannot recognize `Activity`

```
public class FormInfoo {
  private Activity activity;//thisLine
  private LinearLayout linearLayout;
  private EditText inputName;
  private EditText inputPhone;
  private EditText inputEmail;
  private CheckBox cbSharePhone;
  private Button btnSubmit;

public FormInfoo(Activity activity) 
{
    this.activity = activity;
    .
    .
    .
}}
```

Comment: Have you import the library you need? " import android.app.Activity;"

Comment: thank you very much i forget this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply forget add this line i think

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

hope its help